# reorder a double type data

Tags: c, casting, byte, bit

I'm trying to create a function in C in Windows that has as input a double (8Bytes) and returns another double but rearranged, that is, the input is B7 ... B0 and the output is B0 ... B7. My compiler gives me an error when working with int and double data.

I thought about taking the input value and make masks with a high level byte (0xFF) and thus separate the 8Bytes that form the double input value, then concatenate them in the order other than the one they entered and get my double output ordered as I want, but it does not work.

The code is the following:

```
double ordena_lineal(double lineal)
{

    // Recibo B7...B0 y devuelvo B0...B7
    uint8_t B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7;
    double lineal_final;

    B0 = lineal&&0xFF;
    B1 = (lineal>>8)&&0xFF;
    B2 = (lineal>>8*2)&&0xFF;
    B3 = (lineal>>8*3)&&0xFF;
    B4 = (lineal>>8*4)&&0xFF;
    B5 = (lineal>>8*5)&&0xFF;
    B6 = (lineal>>8*6)&&0xFF;
    B7 = (lineal>>8*7)&&0xFF;

    lineal_final = (B7 | (B6 << 8) | (B5 << 8*2) | (B4 << 8*3) | (B3 << 8*4) | (B2 << 8*5) | (B1 << 8*6) | (B0 << 8*7))
    return lineal_final;
}
```

Comment: Shifts are not defined on double. You need to find another trick. Your idea was good though.

Comment: `&&` is the logical AND operator, not the bitwise `AND` operator. Since 0xFF is non-zero, you're assigning the value `1` to `B0`...`B7`

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators are illegal to be used on floating point types.  Also, when you assign the shifted bytes back to  `lineal_final`, you're assigning the *value* of that expression, not its *representation*.

You need to use a `union` to do what you intend.

```
union double_bytes {
    double d;
    uint8_t b[sizeof(double)];
};

double ordena_lineal(double lineal)
{
    union double_bytes src, dst;
    src.d = lineal;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
        dst.b[sizeof(double) - 1 - i] = src.b[i];
    }

    return dst.d;
}
```

This allows you to access the object representation of a `double` and perform aliasing in a standard compliant manner.

Comment: Are unions really necessary here?  If dealing with things on the level of bytes, you should be able to just alias with a char pointer.

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the standard to find that you can't write through a char pointer alias?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Section 6.5p7 discusses how an object can be accessed.

Comment: Yes, @dbush, and one of the ways that 6.5/7 allows the stored value of any object to be accessed is via an lvalue of character type.  The term "accessed" used in that part of the standard encompasses both reading and writing, so yes, you may modify an object's value via a char pointer.

Comment: With that piece of code, would I get the input value with the byte order changed? I regret my low level of programming, I've only been programming for 3 months.

Comment: I believe I've actually seen the "effective type" section used to argue that you cannot legally modify one member of a union and then read it as another member of a union, but in regards to char access, as John Bollinger points out, paragraph 7 explicitly allows access as a character type without giving any restrictions about reading versus writing.